# How to get value of "string"?

Tags: python, string

Given strings like:

```
"hello"
'hello'
```

I want to remove **only** first and last char if:

1. They are the same
2. They are `"` or `'`

I.e., given `'hello'` I'm expecting `hello`. Given `'hello"` I'm not expecting it to change.

I was able to do this by reading first char and last char, validating they are the same + validating they are equal to `'` or `"` and validating it's **not** the the same index for char (because I don't want this: `'` to end up as the empty string). With all edge cases checking I ended with 10s of lines.

What's your approach to solve this?

In simple words, Given a string in Python format I want to return its data and if it's not valid to keep it as is.

Comment: Note, I am expecting this: "" and this '' to be empty word

Comment: @ScottHunter It seems pretty obvious that OP is here looking for a better approach.

Comment: If you have code that works but you want it to be improved, then a) please include it in your post to make a [mcve] so that we can offer specific help and b) consider posting to [codereview.se] instead as that is the site for code review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) with groups:

```
import re
re.sub(r'^([\'"])(.*)(\1)$', r'\2', s)
```

Which reads as:

- `^` - match the beginning of the string
- `(['"])` - either single or double quote (group 1)
- `(.*)` any (possibly, empty) sequence of characters in between (group 2)
- `(\1)` - the same character as in group 1
- `$` - end of the string

If the string matches the pattern above, replace it with the content of the group 2.

For example:

```
>>> s = re.sub(r'^([\'"])(.*)(\1)$', r'\2', "'hello'")
>>> print(s)
hello
```

An alternative way could be with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but it won't handle non-matching quotes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with re, how should I read the output?

Comment: @David I've updated the answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use str.endswith and str.startswith, although it still gets a bit long:

```py
def readstring(string):
    if len(string)>1 and (string.startswith('"') and string.endswith('"') or string.startswith("'") and string.endswith("'")):
        return string[1:-1]
    return string
```